# How to show a loading image before Post method populates the div

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have very simple question

I have following POST method script . Since it does lot of downloading stuff it takes time before getting the response so I am trying to add an image before it sends the response

**Script:**

```
var posting = $.post(url, {
    im_core: 'priviewPropiedades',
    idPropiedad: val,
    idFeed: feedId,
    pais: pais
}).done(function (data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert(json.Descripción);
    $('#Alquiler').html(json.Alqiler);
    $('#Celular').html(json.Celular);
    $('#Construcción').html(json.AConstruceon);
});
```

Can any one tell me where to incorporate the image in the post() method call

Comment: put image in your code in hidden mode and just show/hide it when your ajax starts/stop executing respectively...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place/show the image before you do the POST ($.post) call and remove/hide it when the success handler is triggered.

Something like:

```
var loaderImg = document.getElementById('#my-loader');
loaderImg.classList.add('visible');

$.post('some/url').done(function(){
    loaderImg.classList.remove('visible');
});
```

The rest is just CSS (implementing the visible class).

Comment: can you give me any link that has some description on how to do the overlay image

Answer (score 1):

when you send request to fetch data through ajax, you can show loading images on those divs. And once you get the response you can fully update the html of that div or you can just hide the loading image in that div.

Answer (score 1):

This is the CSS you can add for a div(add class `overlay-bg` to it) and just hide and show it when ajax starts or stops.

```
.overlay-bg { 
display: none; 
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
height:100%; 
width: 100%; 
cursor: pointer; 
z-index: 1000; 
background-image:url('../images/overlay.png'); // here load a downloader kind of image from google or anywhere
background-repeat:repeat; 
background-position:left top; 
}
```